# Howto sync database with git and git hooks and howto debug if it doesn't work

Tags: git, bash, synchronization, mysql, githooks

On OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I've got a drupal deployment (live website) and a staging environment (test website) on my server. Each time I pull changes from my staging website I want to synchronize the database automatically, as instructed here: http://ben.kulbertis.org/2011/10/synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks/

The setup I use is exactly the same (with settings and paths according to my setup of course).

**Quote from the website:**

> Let’s start with pre-commit. The pre-commit hook will run a script directly before a commit is executed. To edit your pre-commit hook:
>
> ```
> [your editor] /path/to/your/repo/.git/hooks/pre-commit
> ```
>
> Now, lets write the pre-commit script. We are going to tell the system to dump our MySQL database to our git repository and add it to be committed.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> mysqldump -u [mysql user] -p[mysql password] --skip-extended-insert [database] > /path/to> /your/repo/[database].sql
> cd /path/to/your/repo
> git add [database].sql
> ```
>
> Now, lets write the post-merge script. We are going to tell the system to restore the MySQL dump to the local database for the latest changes. Edit the post-merge hook with:
>
> ```
> [your editor] /path/to/your/repo/.git/hooks/post-merge
> ```
>
> And write:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> mysql -u [mysql user] -p[mysql password] [database] < /path/to/your/repo/[database].sql
> ```

But when I do a commit and then a pull, nothing seems to happen. The post-merge and pre-commit hooks reside in my hooks dir of the deployment repository from which I conduct the commit and pull. Both have execution rights: `chmod +x /path/to/hook`

I have tested the commands I have placed in the hooks. They should work correctly.

Any way to debug what's wrong?

Comment: Were you able to figure out what went wrong? I'm trying to debug the exact same situation - same hooks and same logic.

Answer (score 0):

For '**post-merge**', if you run a '**git pull**' and are already up to date, then the '**post-merge**' hook won't run.

It seems that the '**pre-commit**' hook will run if no files in your repository have changed. Just make sure there are no spaces after any commands in your script.

It's really disappointing and I'd love to see a '**pre-pull**' hook and a '**pre-commit**' hook that both run irregardless of changes to the repository.

Then again, I'm not a developer, so I may be missing something here. . .

Edit: Just testing this to make sure I've got that correct.

Comment: Why, in this instance, would you want to do a post-merge if you're already up-to-date? If the [database].sql hasn't changed in the branch you're merging from then there's no reason to run `mysql` to commit the the changes to the database.